# Ensuring that UTF-8 encoded string will fit in 2048 bytes

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing a C#/WinForms application that contains a DataGridView with 2,000 rows.  My users will enter strings into these rows.  The strings may be in any language but the two most likely languages are English and Arabic.  I don't have an explicit limit on the maximum number of characters in a string, per se, but what I do have is a limit of 2048 bytes to store each string when it is written to disk.  If the resulting byte array is < 2048 bytes, I need to pad it with null characters.  I'm assuming that UTF-8 would probably be the most efficient encoding for storing these strings?  If so, then I was thinking that I would do something like this before allowing the string to be stored:

```
byte[] stringAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
if (stringAsBytes.Length > 2048)
{
    // string is too long to be stored in 2048 bytes
}
```

If I understand correctly, since UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding, the maximum number of characters in a given string will be dependent on the code point range for the characters that comprise the language of the string?  If that's right, would I really need to do something like the code above for each key press to determine exactly when the string has exceeded the maximum size for storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can use the following code:

```
var encoding=Encoding.UTF8;
var requiredBytes=encoding.GetByteCount("hello world!");
```

Alternatively, you could limit string length to

```
2048 / encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1)
```

which would guarantee all strings of your encoding fit into the buffer. Unfortunately, that's only 341 chars for UTF8.

Comment: It probably makes sense to combine these two approaches. If the string is less than 2048 / encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1) then you're guaranteed to be safe. However, if it's more, then you can do the GetByteCount method to get an exact count.

Comment: I get 682 as maximal number of `char`s (UTF-16 code-units) that are guaranteed to fit 2048 bytes when UTF-8 encoded. Or if you measure in code-points, then 512 are guaranteed to fit into 2048 bytes with UTF-8.

Comment: The number 341 doesn't make any sense, it's either 682 `char`s/UTF-16 code units or 512 characters/code points that fit in 2048 bytes when encoded as utf-8. According to documentation it should return `682`

Comment: Ok now it all makes sense, `Encoding.UTF8` has BOM enabled which is included in the calculations, so when passing `1` as an argument, you get the bytes for bom + the actual maximum for a C# char (`3`). When you pass 2, you get 6+3 and so on. So for this answer to work, it needs to be `(2048 / (encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1)-3)` or `encoding` needs to be `new UTF8Encoding(false)`